# Designing a multi-parameter search

Tags: search, filter, system

I have a pretty complex issue to share with you. I'm working on a financial system, which will provide its customers the option to make a search by more than one parameter.

I'm trying to keep the search bar as simple as possible, and give-up on the "advanced search" option. The problem is that it is very complicated to make it clear for the user that the "enter" button is not taking him/her straight to search, it is just adding a new parameter for the search. How would you make it easy to understand?

Comment: Please be more specific. Is the enter button the only button and is there always a next parameter to enter? Or is there also a button to quickly search the entered key words? There is a text field to enter key words right? But that is why you have to be more specific, to avoid such questions and assumptions in the answers. Can you add images as well that show the idea? That will make it even easier to communicate.

Comment: Hi @Dina a little more context would help, can you add a sketch to demonstrate the search bar you're describing?

Answer (score 1):

Use a clearer action than “Enter”. If the user is always going to add a parameter as Step 2, the button should say something like “Add”. When the system has enough input to perform the search, the user should then see a button that says “Search”.

Comment: I think OP meant the physical Enter button on the keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I am thinking about:
https://codepen.io/songsammy/full/rNwaeda
Two buttons, one for adding a parameter, the other to do search, and a small button to delete parameter.
And I believe that `Advanced Search` is not bad. Just look at Github Advances search.
https://github.com/search/advanced  [image: Github Advanced Search Screeenshot]

Comment: And, Just disable `Enter` on the keyboard. Or , the default behaviour.